# Returning Json data from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

```
   public ActionResult About()
    {
        List<Stores> listStores = new List<Stores>();
        listStores = this.GetResults("param");
        return Json(listStores, "Stores", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Using the above code I am able to get the below result

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Store1","cust_name":"custname1","telephone":"1233455555","email":"abc@ac.com","geo":{"latitude":"12.9876","longitude":"122.376237"}},

{"id":"2","name":"Store2","cust_name":"custname2","telephone":"1556454","email":"nfnf@ac.com","geo":{"latitude":"12.9876","longitude":"122.376237"}},
```

How would I able to get the result in below format?

```
{

"stores" : [
{"id":"1","name":"Store1","cust_name":"custname1","telephone":"1233455555","email":"abc@ac.com",
"geo":{"latitude":"12.9876","longitude":"122.376237"}},

{"id":"2","name":"Store2","cust_name":"custname2","telephone":"1556454","email":"nfnf@ac.com","geo":{"latitude":"12.9876","longitude":"122.376237"}} ] 
}
```

I would like to have the `stores` at the beginning of the data.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to create an object that contains the stores within a property named stores:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var result = new { stores = this.GetResults("param") };
    return Json(result, "Stores", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I've used an anonymous type for simplicity here, if this result type were required in multiple places you may consider creating a 'proper' class for it.

Answer (score 1):

`JavaScriptSerializer` can be found from namespace `System.Web.Script.Serialization`

```
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonStores = ser.Serialize(stores);

return Json(new { stores: jsonStores }, "Stores", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send object to client side as Json format
like Data-table,List,Dictionary etc. then need to override jsonResult and ExecuteResult

other wise use linq format to return data
like

using JSON.NET(must need to use override jsonResult and ExecuteResult )

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();//some data in table
   return json("data",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt))
```

---

other option using linq

```
var Qry = (from d in dt.AsEnumerable()
                               select new
                               {
                                   value = d.Field<int>("appSearchID"),
                                   text = d.Field<string>("appSaveSearchName"),
                                   type = d.Field<int>("appSearchTypeStatus")
                               });
                     return json("Data", Qry);
```

override methods

```
 protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
        {
            try
            {
                    return new JsonNetResult
                    {
                        Data = data,
                        ContentType = contentType,
                        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
                        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
                        MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
                    };

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
        {
           public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                    response.ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) ? "application/json" : this.ContentType;
                    if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
                        response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
                    if (this.Data == null)
                        return;
                    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        response.Write(this.Data);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Although your answer might fix the problem, try to explain `WHY` it fixes the problem. Point out some things that you've changed / fixed to make it work. This will help OP to `understand` why your answer fixes his problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class StoresViewModel{
    public List<Stores> stores {get;set;}
}


public ActionResult About()
{
        List<Stores> listStores = new List<Stores>();
        listStores = this.GetResults("param");
        StoresViewModelmodel = new StoresViewModel(){
            stores = listStores;
        }
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```