# Autocomplete returning 500 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem getting a search form to autocomplete in MVC4 razor, using jQuery and AJAX.

My HTML Form

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.TextBox("FriensList")
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    }
```

My JS Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#FriensList").autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/User/FriendList",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.label };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 1000
    });
})
```

and my controller

```
public ActionResult FriendList(string term)
    {
        using (var db = new dbContext())
        {
            var result = db.UserProfiles
                .Where(r => r.FirstName.Contains(term))
                .Take(10)
                .Select(r => new {label = r.FirstName});

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Debugging the code, I can see that it enters the action when I type a letter into the search box, which returns the correct data from the database, but when the ajax receives the response, it seems to give a 500 error.

I have ensured that my script is being loaded after the js bundles and I added minLength and Delay parameters as suggested in similar question that were previously asked.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit 1**

I changed the controller to

```
public ActionResult FriendList(string term)
    {
        using (var db = new dbContext())
        {
            var result = db.UserProfiles
                .Where(r => r.FirstName.Contains(term))
                .Take(10)
                .Select(r => new {label = r.FirstName});

            var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var tests = ser.Serialize(result);

            return Json(tests, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

now when I search I get a load of li tags under the searchbox. It doesnt print any text, but seems to be repeating over something that isn't the results

**Edit 2**

I changed the return to

```
return Json(tests, "Label", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and the following ajax

```
return { label: item};
```

and now it prints out each separate character in a separate line, including the json brackets

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but a 500 error indicates a problem on the server, meaning something is going wrong with your asp code. Is there a server log you can examine?

Comment: [This may help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326754/returning-json-data-from-mvc-controller)

Comment: Its just running locally on my machine, the error only shows in the JS console in chrome. I will see if I can find any logs that might indicate where the problem lies

Comment: Are you sure you meant `@Html.TextBox("FriensList")`, instead of `FriendsList`?

Comment: Also, @Teeg is right. HTTP 500 means a server issue. You see it in JS console as it was the request response of your page. Consoles usually shows response codes whenever it's not a `200 (OK)`.

Comment: I will look for logs locally on my machine so, thanks for your help. The name is FriensList in both the jQuery and the html, but I fixed it in both anyway. It didn't change anything.

Comment: I cant access the logs as I am running it directly from VS2012 debugger. I will try setting it up in IIS tomorrow and getting at the logs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Json` method internally serializes data to JSON format, so you dont have to explicitly serialize the data.Try `//var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer(); //var tests = ser.Serialize(result); return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @shakib That's the one, thanks very much. Can you write this as an answer and I will mark it as correct? Thanks very much, I appreciate it.

Comment: @DiscoDamo you are welcome. added as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json` method internally serializes data to JSON format, so you dont have to explicitly serialize the data.

```
//var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
//var tests = ser.Serialize(result); 
return Json(result.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The first draft did not work because `result` was of type `IQueryable<T>` which is not the data but a query expression. To explicitly collect data from the query expression `.ToList()` method needs to be called, hence `result.ToList()`.

hope this helps.